# How can I change the location of my Personal folders?

Tags: release-freya, file-management

I want to change the path of the personal folders I see in my Home (Downloads, Music, Documents, etc) to locations on my Windows partition.

I've tried editing the file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` with something like:

```
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR = "/media/Documents/Documents/Downloads"
```

This doesn't seem to work. What's the best way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Why does it not work? What functionality have you lost? Why do you need them moved, and what changes when you move them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Symlinks might be what you are looking for.

1. Delete (or rename if you want to keep the files within) `~/Downloads` folder.
2. In terminal type out the equivalent of:

   ```
   ln -s /media/Documents/Documents/Downloads /home/pablo/
   ```

This would create a link to your windowsdrive, such that when you use your ~/Downloads folder it would be as using `/med../Downloads`.

Very handy thing with config files etc. and for example Dropbox, for creating a kind of sync between all your computers.

This would not "Change the location" of the folders. But it would change where the data you altered in these folders would be saved. I think this is essentially what you are after.

Comment: Es una forma, pero la verdad quería saber por que no funciona modificando el archivo user-dirs. Antes tenía ubuntu y me andaba.

Answer (score 6):

After editing `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file you have to run this command:

```
xdg-user-dirs-update
```

Comment: Hice eso pero no funcionó tampoco